# My Visual Studio can't find files and so can't do basic operations. What's wrong with it?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Using C++, if I launch an 'empty project', create a new C++ file, and try to run it, I just get this error message:

> Unable to run program 'C:\Users\User\source\repos\Project2\Debug\Project2.exe' The system cannot find the file specified

I go to the file it's referencing and the file IS there -- what??

Using a 'Console App' project is different: it will actually compile and run the code.

Similarly, I can't join new header files to the main file, not even in a 'Console App' project: if I write the code for doing `#include "Header.h"`, I get a red line underneath `#include`, and if I hover over that it says:

> cannot open source file "Header.h"

I'm new to coding, and don't know why I'm having such a seemingly absurd problem here. Help!

Comment: Try pressing the "Show All Files" button at the tool bar. It's in the solution explorer, two buttons right of the "Refresh" button. Try adding files now. Working with the file system in this view generally works better imo. Not sure if that solves your problem though.

Comment: Did you check for build errors? Obviously if the build failed and didn't create an executable you can't run or debug your program because there is none. If the build was a success and you get this problem your antivirus may be the source of the problem. Or you changed the settings in your project settings in such a way that you changed the path to the executable to run and it's different from the path that the linker produced. With all of this said your question requires us to guess what is happening because you gave us so little information.

Comment: ***cannot open source file "Header.h"*** This could mean you did not name the header the same as you say in your source file. It could also be related to the file manager setting of "hide extensions for known types" what I mean by that is if you have this on a file named header.h.h could easily be confused with a file named header.h

Comment: Your first step is to figure out if this file `C:\Users\User\source\repos\Project2\Debug\Project2.exe` exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the result you described, I suspect you used `File -> New file` to add that cpp file, right? This does NOT add that file to a project.

Instead, you should right-click the Project file in the Solution explorer, select `Add new item` (or `Project -> Add new item` menu), and choose the `C++` file type.

This works!

Comment: Thank you so much! This completely solved the file extension problem. Thank you.

Comment: @GalenBurnett you are welcome! Could you please accept the answer to indicate that your question is resolved?

Comment: Can't see any button for that--site probably hates me and won't give me access to such a button.

Comment: @GalenBurnett https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: Gotcha. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a new project and then create a c++ file. While adding a file, make sure to select c++ console application and do not check empty project if you are new.

Comment: Sure. Thanks to the fellow above here, I'm now able to make file extensions to a console project. I don't understand why I can't use an empty project like tutorials suggest to do. Would the explanation go over my head as a beginner? As long as I know there's a good reason for it not working and that it's not because my windows pc is just incompetent...